# How for find x for a fitted exponential function?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, mathematical-optimization

```
fp.append(np.polyfit(train_x, train_y, 2))
f.append(np.poly1d(fp))
print(np.poly1d(fp))
threshold = fsolve(f, 50)
```

The above code finds x values for y=50 successfully. But when I try to do the same for the fitted exponential function, I can't understand how to do that.

```
def f_exp(x, a, b, c):
    y = a * np.exp(-b * x) + c
    return y
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f_exp, train_x, train_y)
print(popt)
threshold = fsolve(f_exp, 50) fails with  :TypeError: f_exp() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'a', 'b', and 'c'
```

if I add *popt then I get

```
threshold = fsolve(f_exp(*popt), 50) fails with: TypeError: f_exp() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'
```

I assume that I need to add x value, but it's the value I'm trying to find... Anyway, adding some value instead of x, leads to another error:

```
threshold = fsolve(f_exp(1, *popt), 50) fails with: TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to pass `f_exp` function with optimized parameters to `fsolve` (i.e. with a, b and c args set to values obtained from `curve_fit`). In order to do so you can use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) function:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f_exp, train_x, train_y)
print(popt)
import functools
# preparing arguments
kwargs = dict(zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], popt))
optimized_f_exp = functools.partial(f_exp, **kwargs)
threshold = fsolve(optimized_f_exp, 50)
```

What we did here is basically made a new function `optimized_f_exp` by partially fixing `a`, `b` and `c` args of your original function to be `popt` (what's exactly why it called *partial*).

Comment: Thanks It works. So far I haven't understood all the line of code. Will read manual.